# Proving that, for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$: $\gcd(m,n)\cdot \text{lcm}(m,n) = mn$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Prove that, for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$: $$\gcd(m,n)\cdot \text{lcm}(m,n) = mn$$
> To prove this use the the 2 proposition you proved before this exercice.

The two propositions where:

> 1. 
>
> Let $G$ be a group, $H\leq G$ and $N \trianglelefteq G$. Then: $$H/(H\cap N) \simeq (HN)/N$$

> 2. 
>
> Let $G$ be a group, $H \trianglelefteq G$ and $N \trianglelefteq G$, such that $N\subseteq H$. Then: $$(G/N)/(H/N)\simeq G/H$$

I was able to prove both propositions very easily using the first homomorphism theorem, but when it comes down to applying the proposition I always have a lot of struggle. How can this be solved?

Edit: I know that [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144709/proof-via-group-theory-mathrmlcma-b-cdot-gcda-b-ab) ask the same question but I'm asking for an alternative solution for this problem using these 2 specific propositions.

Comment: Hint: You might find useful to think of $G=\mathbb{Z}$, and take as subgroups $m \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \mathbb{Z}$. The idea here is that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $n$, and that $n\mathbb{Z} + m\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d$ is the gcd, $n \mathbb{Z} \cap m \mathbb{Z}=e\mathbb{Z}$ where $e$ is the lcm.

Comment: Please *search* first to avoid posting duplicate questions.

Comment: How is this a duplicate question? The problem might be the same, in this question I'm exploring a different approach to solving said problem. Don't think this should be marked as a duplicate @BillDubuque

Comment: Of course it is not a duplicate. @BillDubuque sees every arithmetic question as a duplicate of questions answered by him or his buddies. Staying on shoulders of giants does it to you.

Comment: @Eduardo For further details see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705645/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308985/242), which explicitly invoke (1) = 2nd isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @markvs But it is a dupe and  the OP has accepted one of the links I gave.